# How to implement wrap property when autogeneratecolumn=true?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

I am using a grid view and I need that whenever any column contains a text longer than it's width, it should wrap the text or it should show the other part of text in new line.
Below is the grid view code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  AllowSorting="True" runat="server" 
        onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="6" CellPadding="4" 
        onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="Vertical">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle Wrap="false" BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle Wrap="false" BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the ItemStyle of the TemplateField to true like this:

```
<ItemStyle Wrap="true" Width="100px" />
```

Comment: what if i am not using any TemplateField ?

Comment: Apply stylesheet class to the grid with word-wrap

Comment: i tried it as  { word-break: break-all; word-wrap: break-word; } but it's not working. is it wrong ?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/guruketepalli/archive/2011/02/02/spgridview-word-wrap.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using different setting for gridview like `ItemStyle` you should write a separate `css class for it`.
here is good link

[Asp.net Css Gridview Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308521/asp-net-css-gridview-styling)
[Fixed Column Headers For ASP.NET Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055193/fixed-column-headers-for-asp-net-gridview)

### Example

```
         <%@ Page Language=" C#" %>

    <head runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .headerStyle
            {
                background-color: #FF6600;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-size: 8pt;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .itemStyle
            {
                background-color: #FFFFEE;
                color: #000000;
                font-size: 8pt;
            }

            .alternateItemStyle
            {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                color: #000000;
                font-size: 8pt;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="ItemsGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                DataKeyNames="ItemID" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemID" HeaderText="Item ID" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="100px"
                        ItemStyle-CssClass="itemStyle" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemName" HeaderText="Item Name" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ClStk" HeaderText="Item closingStock" ReadOnly="true"
                        ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
                </Columns>
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternateItemStyle" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle" />
            </asp:GridView>

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: but i am not using any boundfield ?

Comment: @Anand what ever you are using it does not matter it will applied weather you are using boundfield or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are auto generating the columns you would need to to use the RowDataBound event to check the length of each column for each row.
Here is the documentation for it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx